# Parameter not passing due to ngIf

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-ng-if

This is .html code

```
<div class="box col-lg-3 sidebar col-3">
  <ul style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y:scroll">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let user of products" [class.selected]="user === selectedPatient" >
         <li  *ngIf="filter(user)" (click)="onSelect(user);" >
            <p>{{ user.name }} {{ filtername }}</p>
        </li>
      </ng-container>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="box col-lg-9 mainpage col-9 " style="padding:0px;">
  <app-doctor-patientview  [patient]="selectedPatient" ></app-doctor-patientview>
  <!--  -->
</div>
```

This is the  component.ts code for above html code

```
  products: any[];
  name: any;
  selectedPatient: Patient;
  filtername: string="";
  show:boolean = true;

onSelect(hero: Patient): void {
  this.selectedPatient = hero;
  console.log(this.selectedPatient);
}

filter(patient : Patient) : boolean{

  if (patient.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.filtername.toUpperCase())>-1){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This is the app-doctor-patientview.html

```
<div *ngIf="patient"></div>
```

code snippet for app-doctor-patientview component.ts

```
    export class DoctorPatientviewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() patient: Patient;
  isOn=1;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

It seems that on including *ngIf in the .html code the selectedPatient parameter is not passing to app-doctor-patientview.

If I do not include *ngIf the parameter passes and the display properly in app-doctor-patientview. How do I solve this error?

Comment: `patient` in ts of your  `app-doctor-patient...` should be truthy..

Comment: @AshishRanjan  I have taken patient value as  @Input() patient: Patient; where Patient is class

Comment: There is something else thats troubling you. See this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxvy3a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts , it works fine, I have added a check for `name` but still it renders, if you can replicate your problem on stackblitz, it will be easier to debug

Comment: You have to add `app-doctor-patientview` component code

Comment: @AshishRanjan i have tried and put it up on stackblitz, do have a look. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdhvca?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html  .

Comment: @Yuva: Your code works fine.. what is the problem there? when you click on any of the `a`, `b` or `c`, I can see `click on the name` text from the child component..